# What is the story behind the "I really hate unicorns" close reason? 

Tags: discussion, meta, close-reasons, unicorns, stack-exchange-history

According to the [Question Close Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats) in the 10k Tools here on Meta Stack Exchange, Shog9 created a new close reason in June 2013 that stated:

> Questions about unicorns are off-topic because I really hate unicorns. For more information, bite my shiny metal horn.

The close reason was apparently removed the same day.

I know that unicorns have been a [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/336163) on Stack Exchange for quite a while, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how that led to this very short-lived close reason.

*What actually happened on the site on June 19, 2013 that triggered the creation and prompt removal of this close reason?*

Comment: Probably some testing in production ...

Comment: Shog was on a bender that day.

Comment: It's a sad tale. Ending in a vat of sparkly glue and some rather questionable meatballs

Comment: I believe that June 2013 was when the current off-topic closing architecture was implemented, so @rene's theory that it was testing makes sense.

Comment: They are inferior to  RBUK.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Meatballs? Don't you mean [breen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVLkxSSvegc)? :-)

Comment: Say, how'd you get 10K rep to have access to the tools? *points to question*

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually - considering history, I probably was.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because I really hate unicorns.